# python convert list items to unicode in a single line

Tags: python, list, unicode, utf-8

This is my code:

```
mylist=['尺','选择']
[x.encode('utf-8') for x in mylist]
```

beofore i could even get to the second line of my file, the script returns an error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe5' in file but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

how do i solve this?

Comment: Did you read http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ ? Seems you need to include you encoding.

Comment: unrelated: Use Unicode to work with text. If it is Python 2 then add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` so that you wouldn't need to add `u''` prefix to every string literal. Don't use non-ascii characters in `bytes` literals; it is explicitly forbidden on Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set *source code encoding* to UTF-8 for this. As per [PEP-0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) , Try setting the below line at the top of the script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

The different styles possible for specifying source code encodings are given in the PEP linked above.